# Memory leak in netty API

Tags: java, netty

I am new to netty API
and I am using netty3.5.2 to develop client and server communication server,
but the app always run full GC,
I use jmap to dump the memory and
use jhat to show which object occupied the memory.
And there are 6413363 instances of  `DefaultChannelFuture`.
can someone tell which thread create the `DefaultChannelFuture` instances
and how and  when they will be released?

Top 4 instances suspected
6413363 instances of class `org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture`
631971  instances of class `org.jboss.netty.util.internal.LinkedTransferQueue$Node`
630934  instances of class `org.jboss.netty.buffer.BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer`
630767  instances of class `org.jboss.netty.channel.DownStreamMessageEvent`

Comment: Can you upload the heap dump somewhere? This would help to see what is going on.

Comment: thanks,but the dump file is very large with 2G byte,I can not upload it

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, try MAT: https://www.eclipse.org/mat/ This will give you good information about leak suspects. I am using Netty 3.6.6 and I have no such problems. Can you post the code of your custom `UpstreamHandler`s and `DownstreamHandler`s?

Answer (score 1):

You generating messages to fast. It overload message queue.

Check nethwork load.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old now so not sure if you have found an answer.  I haven't used it but the [Netty in Action](http://www.manning.com/maurer/) book describes a leak detector:

> Netty contains a so called `ResourceLeakDetector` which will sample about 1% of buffer allocations to check if there is a leak in your application.
>   In case of a detected leak you will see a log message similar to the following:
>
> LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Enable advanced
>           leak reporting to find out where the leak occurred. To enable advanced leak
>           reporting, specify the JVM option
>
> `-Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced` or
>           call 
>   `ResourceLeakDetector.setLevel()`